# Fetching A Particular data from a api call

Tags: javascript, html, json, api, server

my js code is

```
    <script>       
    fetch('https://api.binance.com/api/v1/trades?symbol=BTCUSDT')
   .then(resi => resi.json())
   .then(data =>(console.log(data)));
    resi.send();
    </script>
```

and from its response one is the below one :

[0 … 99]
   0:
   id: 96874552
   isBestMatch: true
   isBuyerMaker: true
   price: "3584.58000000"
   qty: "0.00293100"
   time: 1548506554914
    **proto**: Object

and i have 100s of result like this. but can i only get qty or price from this and store each in to a variable using arrays?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create new array of objects you want.

In your case:

```
fetch('https://api.binance.com/api/v1/trades?symbol=BTCUSDT')
   .then(resi => resi.json())
   .then(data => data.map(item => Object({"qty":item.qty, "price":item.price}));
    resi.send();
```

Then `data` will contain an array of 100 items with `qty` and `price` only.

Comment: but it shows nothing.Can you confirm It?i also tried  .then(data => console(data.map(item => Object({"qty":item.qty, "price":item.price})))); (added console fnc)